# AngularJS. Set default header depending on current route

Tags: angularjs

I need to set default header in $http service depending on current route. This is the code:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.HeaderName = 'HeaderValue';
```

I need to watch current `$location.path` and change value of the header according the route.

Can I put this code in $routeProvider section? Something like:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/route', {
        templateUrl: 'book.html',
        controller: 'BookController',
        resolve: function() {
                     //set default header here
        }
    })
```

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: inject $location to your controller

Comment: but how can I set default header in controller?

Comment: are you asking how to get the route? $location.path() will be '/route'  base on your example. set the header like your example.

Comment: The problem is that I can't set global headers in controller. At least I don't know how

Comment: I read your question a few more times very carefully, my understanding is you need to set http headers base on your current route. that means when you change route, you need a different headers. So why do you need to set headers in default $httpProvider. all services in angular is singleton.

Comment: You have understood my question correctly. I need to all my $http requests contain header, depended on route. I can add `{headers: {'headerName': 'headerValue'}` to each request manually. But I'm looking for the way to do it once. Please, explain the solution you offered (based on fact that services are singletons)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$routeProvider` is a provider, but on the other hand `$http` is an instance, so basically you **cannot inject an instace to config block** where you set `$routeProvider`, but **you can inject $http instance to run block** which suits you most...

ok let's deal the problem you face, actually you can do it any controller you want but you want it to do when **only location/route changes** so let's inject another instance $rootScope to run block to watch location/route changes...

but you have one more request set `$http.defaults` depends on `$location.path()` so let's inject another instance `$location` to run block to get current path...

**so here is our final run block**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.HeaderName = $location.path();
    console.log("Headers :",$http.defaults.headers);
  });
});
```

from now on after every location change trigger our watch where we set `$http.headers` depends on `$location.path()`...

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bu4dQyNKOwxyPVkma3mk?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

if you want to look other `$route` and `$location` events check this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/JIaGj1?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the header based on location by listening to the `$routeChangeStart` event, and changing the defaults there:

```
$rootScope.$on( '$routeChangeStart', function() {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.headerName = 'Path is ' + $location.path();
});
```